# Does the size of Timber global $context has impact on performance

Tags: performance, optimization, timber

Trying to optimise website and was wondering does this have some impact.

I'm adding to `$context` some variables...

````php
  public function add_to_context( $context ) {
    $context['query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars;
    $context['menu'] = new Timber\Menu('main-menu', array( 'depth' => 2 ));
    ...
    $context['footer_menu'] = new \Timber\Menu( 'footer-main-menu' );
    $context['footer_support'] = new \Timber\Menu( 'footer-support-menu' );
    $context['footer_legal'] = new \Timber\Menu( 'footer-legal-menu' );```
````

Comment: Timber comes with a [timer helper](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-helper/#start_timer), you can use this to see just how much of a performance impact it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use `transient API`

Also, there is some document about Timber caching.  https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/performance/

Also, check this part too. https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/performance/#measuring-performance That is what you wonder about.